# Calling jQuery on (window).load and passing variable for 'No Conflict' code

Tags: jquery, window-load

I recently learnt, the very handy trick, that lets you pass the $ in the jQuery function so that you all the contained code is in a No Conflict mode. The advantage being that you can write all the contained code with the '$' instead of 'jQuery'.

This code works fine...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
// My code
});
```

This code does not work...

```
jQuery(window).load(function( $ ){
// My code
});
```

It says '$ is not a function'. How to I get it to work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create an (anonymous) self-invoking function, and pass the `jQuery` object as shown below:

```
(function($){  //This functions first parameter is named $
   $(window).load(function(){
       // Your code
   });
})(jQuery);    //Passing the jQuery object as a first argument
```

Comment: Why is this required? And should you always use this, even when using document.ready in no-conflict mode?

Comment: @jjeaton By using a closure as shown above, you are 100% certain that `$` inside that function always refers to the jQuery object at that time (otherwise, `$` might be overwritten at a later point, causing an unpredictable error). The actual problem in the question is that the OP assumes that `$` in `.load(function($) ... )` is a jQuery object (which is not - see the documentation of [`.load()`]()http://api.jquery.com/load/). The first example works, because it's actually a documented feature of `.ready`, again read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/