# More efficient way to wait for all images to load in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dom

I'm using a mix of `.ready()` and `.load()` to execute my desired function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("img").load(function() {
        // Function goes here
    });
});
```

As you can see, this waits for the DOM to be ready, then on each `<img>` load, it executes the code.

If I only had one image to load this would be simple.

But the problem is -- what if I have **10 images** to be loaded? The function will be called **10 times** due to each image loading one by one, and that's not a very efficient way to go about it just to achieve what I want.

So here's the question -- is there a more efficient way to **wait for all images to load, then execute the function once**?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin

Comment: Dup: [Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin?rq=1) (See second answer)

Comment: @asymptoticFault I'm asking to execute **once**, not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin which is just asking to execute (multiple times) on load.

Comment: @Izkata Will look at the 2nd answer to see if its what I need, thanks

Comment: The linked answer does only execute once when all images have loaded.

Comment: @asymptoticFault right, will see if it works, if it does i'll delete the thread.

Comment: @asymptoticFault last note before i flag for a delete -- it does. changed the script to `(function($) {$(window).load(function(){//Code Here});})(jQuery);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody wants to know, my final result was this:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        // Function goes here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

that's because

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {});
```

isn't a jQuery object, as referenced in this question:

[Calling jQuery on (window).load and passing variable for 'No Conflict' code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543828/calling-jquery-on-window-load-and-passing-variable-for-no-conflict-code)

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this to avoid having your function run multiple times.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var nrOfImages = $("img").length;
    $("img").load(function() {
        if(--nrOfImages == 0)
        {
            // Function goes here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    alert("page finished loading now.");
});
```

`jQuery(window).load(...)` will be triggered after all content on the page has been loaded. This different from `jQuery(document).load(...)` which is triggered after the DOM has been loaded. I think this will solve your issue.